# 90s(?) young adult sci-fi anthology book, including a girl astronaut going to a smell-less world and a merman-looking boy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, anthology-book

I'm looking for a compilation of YA sci-fi short stories which I read in high school in the mid 90s.

The book had two stories which I remember:

1. Was about a girl astronaut who goes to another world just like ours but without smell. Except if you're dying, then you smell lovely.
2. Was about a boy with gold eyes and pointy teeth that is merman-like.

I loved this book as a kid, **what is the name of this book?**